# VBA - Add new Column then COPY cells and then SUM cells

Tags: vba, excel, range, ms-office

I am attempting to create a new column that consolidates multiple values into a single Column. The code below has no problems creating a new column exactly where I need it.

Within each newly created column however, I would like my code to Sum the previous 5 cells within the same row. It works currently, but is static(The new column is G in the below example, and it sums B:F). I think I need some sort of Offset function built into it to allow the Range it sums to be dynamic (Previous 5 columns), as it loops through the entire sheet.

Additionally, I would love it to copy the Header information from rows 1-9 from the column to the left of the new column, into the new column, and place the word "Combo" into Row 10 of the new column.

Office 2013

Any help with this endeavor would be great.
Thanks

```
Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim columnHeading As String

For currentColumn = Sheets("SLTData").UsedRange.Columns.Count To 2 Step -1

columnHeading = Sheets("SLTData").UsedRange.Cells(10, currentColumn).Value

'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
Select Case columnHeading
    Case "PD.G0100", "PD.G0500", "PD.G0800", "PD.G0900", "PD.G1000", "PD.G0300", "PD.G0400", "PD.G0150", "PD.G0600"
        'Do nothing
    Case Else

        If InStr(1, _
           Sheets("SLTData").UsedRange.Cells(10, currentColumn).Value, _
           "Homer", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then


            Sheets("SLTData").Columns(currentColumn).Insert
                For i = 11 To Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                Range("G" & i) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B" & i), Range("C" & i), Range("D" & i), Range("E" & i), Range("F" & i))
                Next i
        End If
End Select
Next
```

Comment: When `currentColumn` is `2`, do you still want to sum the five columns to the left of it (i.e. column `A`, column `0`, column `-A`, column `-B`, and column `-C`, of which only column `A` will be valid)?  And note that `Range`, `Cells` and `Rows` in your code are referring to the `ActiveSheet`, which may or may not be `Sheets("SLTData")`.  (You should always qualify references to `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Range("G" & i)` use `Cells(row, column)` (both row and column are integer). To sum up the 5 cells left of it: `Cells(row, column) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(row, column-5), Cells(row, column-1)))`

Comment: AWESOME!  Thank You!